# How to connect a custom wifi network in the emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Team, I set up an android emulator in my mac [Api level 28, os 9]
I can see by default it is connected to 'androidwifi'.
How do i connect the same emulator to my corporate wifi so that i can test my app inside that.

Answer (score 0):

Your emulator will use your computer's hardware to emulate every relevant aspect of the hardware of a real device. Likewise, the "androidwifi" network is a simulation of the actual wifi network that your computer is connected to.

If you want to change the settings and test different speeds/latency/etc you can do it via the emulator settings. Some of them (eg. netspeed) can be further configured manually with commands. [Here's a list](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html#startup-options) from the developer's guide.